# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " when adding a value to an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the weird thing is that I get in my alert the proper values, but not in my

```
$('kl_naam').val();

     var _naam="",
    _voornaam="",
    _straat="",
    _post="",
    _gem="",
    _firma="",
    data="";
    function getFsmaGeg(str){

   $.ajax({
            url: 'classes/FsmaGeg.php?inscript='+str,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function() {
                //updateAfspraak(final);
            },
            type: 'post',
            complete: function(data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                alert(data.straat);
            if(data) {

                    _naam=data.naam ;
                    _voornaam=data.voornaam ;
                    _straat=data.straat ;
                    _post=data.post ;
                    _gem=data.gem ;
                    _firma=data.firma ;

                    //checkStep1();
                }
            }
        });
        $('#kl_voornaam').val()=_voornaam;
        $('#kl_naam').val()=_naam;
        $('#kl_straat').val()=_straat;
        $('#kl_postcode').val()=_post;
        $('#kl_gemeente').val()=_gem;
        $('#kl_firma').val()=_firma;

    alert(_naam+" "+_voornaam+" "+_straat);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should parse the data like

```
   data = JSON.parse(data);
```

To assign a value to an `input` do

```
   $(input-selector).val(value);
```

In your case

```
function getFsmaGeg(str){

   $.ajax({
    url: 'classes/FsmaGeg.php?inscript=' + str,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function () {
        //updateAfspraak(final);
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(data.straat);
        if (data) {

            _naam = data.naam;
            _voornaam = data.voornaam;
            _straat = data.straat;
            _post = data.post;
            _gem = data.gem;
            _firma = data.firma;

            $('#kl_voornaam').val(_voornaam);
            $('#kl_naam').val(_naam);
            $('#kl_straat').val(_straat);
            $('#kl_postcode').val(_post);
            $('#kl_gemeente').val(_gem);
            $('#kl_firma').val(_firma);

        }
    }
});


alert(_naam + " " + _voornaam + " " + _straat);
}
```

Comment: Thx how could I forget, but I still don't get the value in the input field. You did solved the error

Comment: This should also be included in the complete handler.

Comment: see the updated answer. You are parsing the `result` wrongly. `data.responseText` should be just `data`.

Comment: with your code I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" on line 1 that is the <html> tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value into the `.val()` method: `$('#k1_voornaam').val(_voornaam)`.

You would set it with `=` if you were using just the DOM API: `document.getElementById('k1_voornaam').value = _voornaam`.